# Calling Templates on demand in SPA

Tags: angularjs, templates, single-page-application, angularjs-routing

In my current SPA application, the index page shows  Login form (default router) which doesn't have **header** & **footer** , 
When User Logs in account , router takes user to after login page and  Header & footer are shown ( as per app requirement). My index.html looks like

```
<code>
    <html>
     <header ng-class="{hide:loginPage}"> 
     </header>
     <ng-view></ng-view>
     <footer ng-class="{hide:loginPage}" ></footer> 
    </html>
</code>
```

but there is a problem. When User Routes to Default Login, fraction of a second The header & footer gets displayed. is there any best way to achieve result

Please guide how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for ng-cloak: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngCloak. Your header and footer are briefly flashing because the hide class isn't applied until the ng-class expression is parsed.

Comment: Yeah even I thought so. but ngCloak is not working for me either.

Comment: ng-cloak relies on angular being loaded in the head or having the ng-cloak class added to an external stylesheet. From the docs: "For the best result, the angular.js script must be loaded in the head section of the html document; alternatively, the css rule above must be included in the external stylesheet of the application."
Are you sure this is case in your app?

Here's a demo: http://embed.plnkr.co/W7Pm4y/preview

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is to add an [ng-include](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInclude) in my  footer and header to selectively load what I need

Check this demo from angular page. It may help:

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInclude